# "No such file or directory" even though the file is listed with ls

Tags: command-line, permissions

I have reinstalled and installed Ubuntu 3 times now.  I'm writing a **gforth** program for the school.  I have installed gforth and it runs just fine.  I've written a file to save my program in.  In the given directory and I use `ls`, the file is listed.  However, if I use the command `gforth filename.fs`, I get `*OS command line*:-1: No such file or directory` followed by a few lines of a backtrace.  Trying to include the file while in gforth creates a similar result.  Even when I try `vim filename.fs`, I get a blank file.  Creating new files with vim also doesn't work.  After I exit vim and save, the file is nowhere to be found.  Please help.

Comment: You sure you didn't put a space or similar invisible character in the filename?

Comment: Yeah, the filename has no spaces or anything, it's literally program.fs

Comment: Are you in the same directory as the file when you call `gforth`  ? Try `gforth ./program.fs`

Comment: That resulted in almost the exact same thing, except instead of saying `No such file or directory` it now says `Permission denied`.  I thought I've been running as the administrator, but I don't know if that even has anything to do with this.

Comment: Go to the directory and run `namei -lx *`, and add the output please.

Comment: The output of `namei -lx *` is `f: filename.fs\n --------- username username filename.fs`.

Answer (score 2):

The output of `namei` shows what the problem is: your file exists, but has permissions `----------`, meaning it is neither readable, writable nor executable by anyone, including the user who owns the file. Try:

```
chmod u+rw program.fs
```

The command `ls -l program.fs` should then show something like

```
 -rw------- 1 username username 0 Nov 22 14:21 program.fs
```

The `rw` means that you have given yourself permission to read and write this file. See e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm for more info.